# Displaying div element on jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi i am trying to display the more than one div into jQuery code.
But it is displaying blank page.

I am not able to figure out what is going wrong.

Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var parent = document.createElement("div");
    parent.className="panel panel-default";

    var heading = document.createElement("div");
    heading.className="panel-heading";

    var h3=document.createElement("h3");
    h3.className="panel-title";
    h3.setAttribute('id','panel_title');

    var t = document.createTextNode("DEMO"); 
    h3.appendChild(t);
    heading.appendChild(h3);

    var pbody=document.createElement('div');
    pbody.className="panel-body";

    var prTable=document.createElement('div');
    prTable.setAttribute('id','print_received_table');
    pbody.appendChild(prTable);

    parent.appendChild(heading);
    parent.appendChild(pbody);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Why jQuery and then not use it.
2. You do not add the generated objects to the body (or result). `document.body.appendChild(parent)` or `$("body").append(parent)` or `parent.appendTo("body")` will work here

**non jQuery version**

```js
 window.onload=function() {
    var parent = document.createElement("div");
    parent.className="panel panel-default";

    var heading = document.createElement("div");
    heading.className="panel-heading";

    var h3=document.createElement("h3");
    h3.className="panel-title";
    h3.setAttribute('id','panel_title');

    var t = document.createTextNode("DEMO"); 
    h3.appendChild(t);
    heading.appendChild(h3);

    var pbody=document.createElement('div');
    pbody.className="panel-body";

    var prTable=document.createElement('div');
    prTable.setAttribute('id','print_received_table');
    pbody.appendChild(prTable);

    parent.appendChild(heading);
    parent.appendChild(pbody);
    document.body.appendChild(parent);
 }
```

**jQuery version**

```js
$(function() {
    var parent = $("<div/>");
    parent.addClass("panel panel-default");

    var heading = $("<div/>");
    heading.addClass("panel-heading");

    var h3=$("<h3/>");
    h3.addClass("panel-title")
      .attr('id','panel_title')
      .text("DEMO"); 

    /* NOTE: The above can be written like this
    var h3 = $("<h3/>", {
     text: "DEMO",
    class: "panel-title",
       id: 'panel_title'
    });
    */

    heading.append(h3);

    var pbody=$("<div/>");
    pbody.addClass("panel-body");

    var prTable=$("<div/>")
    prTable.attr('id','print_received_table');
    pbody.append(prTable);

    parent.append(heading);
    parent.append(pbody);
    $("body").append(parent);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you wanna append into `#result` element, every elements created so far did't added into page unless you append into `body` or element that already existed on that page, use below code to append into element with id `result` :

```
......
parent.appendChild(pbody);
// append parent element into result element
document.getElementById('result').appendChild(parent);
```